# Why is ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText in System.Web.Mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I know this is not a regular type question for SO, but still... there exists no other better place to know the answer to this question but SO, so...

While working on a service project, I found out that I could not use [`ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428394(v=vs.118).aspx) that I am used to using in my mvc project. This is due to the fact that my service project does not have reference to `System.Web.Mvc` (as expected), and that method exists in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly.

My question is why is that method `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText()` in `System.Web.Mvc` assembly? It is not like the projects without reference to `System.Web.Mvc` assembly do not ever need to obtain the property name from expression. So why did the developers choose to put this utility method in that assembly? Is it something like .net team were not introducing such a utility method, and hence the mvc team took it to themselves to add it? ;-)

Comment: Its a method used in the `HtmlHelper` methods (which are mvc specific). Perhaps there are other similar utility methods in other assemblies where it might be required

Comment: I agree, it has very little dependencies within `System.Web.Mvc`. Perhaps you could raise your question over on [github](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC)?

Comment: One possible reason is that the method also uses a cache (the `CachedExpressionCompiler` defined in `System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionUtil` namespace)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ indeed, this seems to be the right [issue tracker](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues)

Comment: @LennartStoop, That issue tracker (your last comment) is for asp.net-core.mvc. For asp.net-mvc its [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues)